# jquery sparklines: box plots and one value

Tags: javascript, boxplot, sparklines

I'm using Sparklines and am trying to draw a simple blox plot with predetermined min, max, whiskers, quartiles,  and one additional value -- the user's value that might fall within the quartile or outside  (the whole point is to show the user where his/her value falls in the distribution)

What is the appropriate way to do this?    I can get a basic box up but can't see how to lay a point on top of it.    Also I can't see how to set min and max but it looks like the outliers sort of do this.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    var myboxvalues = [0, 200, 450, 500, 550, 800, 1000];
    $('.inlinebox').sparkline( myboxvalues, {type: 'box', raw: true });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
My box: <span class="inlinebox"></span>
</p>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flag is  "target:  ..."

```
{type: 'box', raw: true, target: 713 }
```